# Database create new guest user

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am creating a chat app, and I need to store every message in a database.
To connect to the database I use this code:

```
 session_start(); 
$servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "admin"; 
$password = "my password"; 
$dbname="my dbname"; 
// Create connection 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 

// Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } 
echo "Connected successfully".'<br>';
```

The connection is done using my admin account,and every time two or more devices are connected,the server crashes.

is there any way I can create a new guest user for each of the users, using PHP, SQL, or something like that?

I am using 000Webhost as hosting service, and the database runs on MariaDB.

Comment: Could you add the actual error that you're getting? If it is just a multiple connection issue, this might be of use https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35183/mysql-maximum-number-of-connections-on-a-per-user-basis-possible

Comment: check your logs then if you have access to them

Comment: The error says: mysql server has gone away

Comment: I don't have acces to the logs

Comment: Complain to the hosting service.  It should be "impossible" for _your app_ to crash the server.

Comment: Terminology?  Elaborate on "crash" and "device".

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution, I am restarting the connection every 2 seconds, and is working fine now.
I set a `<meta>` to do so